# How can I make the items in QTreeWidget expanded by default?

Tags: qt

I have to call expandAll() in the constructor, but that looks unnecessary,

[image]

The stuff I've added in form editor was just collapsed, and I failed to find an property in the right box, how should I make it all expanded by default?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
setExpanded(true);
```

for the parent(s) of

```
QTreeWidgetItem
```

For example:

```
QTreeWidget *treewidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
QTreeWidgetItem *tools = new QTreeWidgetItem(treewidget);
tools->setExpanded(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote simple programm with QTreeWidget.
Assistant qt has description of property `itemsExpandable()`:

> This property holds whether the items are expandable by the user. This
>   property holds whether the user can expand and collapse items
>   interactively. By default, this property is true.

And as you said, QTreeWidget has expandAll() slot.

I called it in constructor. This slot works right.

Comment: I was trying to avoid calling that, I want items expanded by default

Comment: Qt Designer can not to set expanded items by default. You should use `expandAll()` in constructor. This is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function to add items and then use it to fill the tree:

```
void addRootNode(const QString& value) {
    QTreeWidgetItem* treeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    treeItem->setText(value);
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItem(treeItem);
    ui->treeWidget->expandItem(treeItem);
}
```